# I have .dat file in s3. I need to read the file through spark and do some filters and load into the S3 again

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a .dat file which is having some 50 columns data in S3 location, need to read through spark and do some filters for 3 columns and load the data into s3 again

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is addressed in this post:
[Read & Write Parquet Files from and to S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47652281/trying-to-read-and-write-parquet-files-from-s3-with-local-spark)

`To access data stored in Amazon S3 from Spark applications, you use Hadoop file APIs (SparkContext.hadoopFile, JavaHadoopRDD.saveAsHadoopFile, SparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD, and JavaHadoopRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile) for reading and writing RDDs, providing URLs of the form s3a://bucket_name/path/to/file. You can read and write Spark SQL DataFrames using the Data Source API.`

Another good Cloudera resource that shows you how to configure your application:
[Access data stored in S3](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/spark_s3.html)